# How to use `httpretty` to mock out request

Tags: python, server, pytest, httpretty

Here's a test I've tried writing:

```py
import httpretty
import requests


@httpretty.activate
def test():

    httpretty.register_uri(
        httpretty.GET,
        "http://localhost:8000",
        body='{"origin": "127.0.0.1"}',
        status=200
    )
    requests.get("http://localhost:8000")
```

When I run it with `pytest`, however, I get

```py
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://httpretty.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), I thought I'd followed it ad verbatim - any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, nor with 3.7 neither with 3.8. I guess the lib is broken, [report it on Github](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/issues/new). There are other comparable libs if need a replacement in the meantime; I have used [`requests-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) successfully. It only mocks `requests` calls though, not the low-level `socket` lib.

Comment: Thanks! I've got around my problem using the pytest plugin `pytest-localserver`

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem with the code block in the question is that when specifying a port, httpretty needs you to include a trailing slash in the url in the call to `register_uri`. There's actually a warning about this in the [documentation for register_uri](https://httpretty.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#register-uri), but it still strikes me as something of a missing stair.

So, the code you would need for your basic example to work is:

```
httpretty.register_uri(
        httpretty.GET,
        "http://localhost:8000/",
        body='{"origin": "127.0.0.1"}',
        status=200
    )
```

I found this [tip](https://coderwall.com/p/w914wa/httpretty-not-working-with-requests) and also ran into my own problems which seem to indicate that maybe specifying a port isn't the only factor in play when it comes to trailing slashes.

I ended up switching to the [responses](https://pypi.org/project/responses/) library, which seems to get along better with pytest fixtures anyway.